# References mixup in java

Tags: java, reference

```
class blabla extends JPanel
{
    public blabla()
    {
    //code
    }
}

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JPanel b;
        ArrayList<blabla> c;

        blabla a = new blabla();

        b = new JPanel();
        c = new ArrayList<blabla>();

        b.add(a);
        c.add(a);

        blabla d = (blabla) b.getComponent(0);
        System.out.println(c.indexOf(d));
     }
}
```

Are `ArrayList a` and `JPanel a` same objects?
What should be the codes output?

Comment: It's hard to tell without the code. All we can give you is more-or-less useful speculation.

Comment: I have rewritten the question...

Comment: Man you have changed the question completely... ??

Comment: It's the thing I want to know...

Comment: Does `blabla` relates to `JPanel`? and there is nothing as `ArrayList a`?

Comment: It extends it. But not really important, it extends it only so I can add it to another JPanel. I guess it could be any JComponent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright here goes the answer for your modified question...

> Are ArrayList a and JPanel a same objects?

No. But they contain the same object of class `blabla`.

> What should be the codes output?

The output is

```
0
```

which is right as you placed the same component in the `JPanel` and `ArrayList` and `0` is the index of element.

Answer (score 3):

**This answer is based upon what you mentioned in the question when no code snippet was provided and quetion was...**

> I have created a component instance, drawn it onto the screen, and added it to an ArrayList.
>   I'm accessing it by referencing to the drawn one using it's children (getParent() method). However, when I then pass this reference to ArrayLists indexOf(); method, it returns -1.
>   I suppose that means that the component does not exist in the ArrayList.
>   Is this what should happen, or did I probably mess something up in my program? I'm NOT providing you with a SSCCE, I'm not asking you to do any coding, just to tell me if this is normal Java behavior...

**Here goes the my response**

The javadoc of `indexOf()` says...

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More formally, returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.

As you can see this depends on the `equals()` implementation for you component. Check your implementation as that holds the key of retrieving the value from list.

Comment: Sorry for changing the question, I saw your answer after I changed it...

Comment: On the related note, I printed out index which it returned, it worked fine, but when I passes the exactly same line of code to the method in very next line, it returned `indexOutOfBounds` exception...